# find the equation of the tangent to $y = \sin x$ at the point where $x = \frac{\pi}3$

Tags: derivatives

> Check workings for find the equation of the tangent to $y = \sin x$ at
>   the point where $x = \frac{\pi}3$.

When $x = \frac{\pi}3$, $y = f(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \sin \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac {\sqrt{3}}2$

$\frac{d}{dx} \sin x = \cos x$

$f'(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{3})  = \frac{1}2$

$(y -\frac {\sqrt{3}}2) = \frac{1}2(x - \frac{\pi}3)$

Answer (score 1):

the equation of a tangent line is given by
$$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+y_0$$
$$f'(x_0)=\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$$
$$y_0=\sin(\pi/3)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: So my answer is correct in $(y_2 - y_1) = m(x_2 - x_1)$ form